# Git SVN rebase to tags only

Tags: svn, git, version-control, tags, git-svn

I'm extending an open source project with additional functionality. So I'll be basing my code on the released version of the source code. The open source project uses SVN and I uses Git.

How would I rebase only to the released version (SVN tags) instead of to the HEAD of trunk when a new version is released?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have [git-svn](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) or some other method of importing commits set up:

```
git rebase releasetag mybranch
```

The tag `releasetag` might import from SVN or it might be a tag you've created yourself with [git-tag](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html), or it could even just be the SHA-1 of a particular commit.